# Dealing with Generics in Apex

Tags: apex, generics

I have some code that i want to try and emulate generics for. I know there are no generics in Apex but is there something we can do instead?

Let me explain

```
(String) sfBorr.get('SSN__pc');
```

sfBorr is an sObject

This line of code will throw an exception if get() returns null. I want to create a method that will catch this error and then just return null if the field is blank but i need to cast the object at some point, which means i would need to check for null every time i assign a field.

Comment: It is hard to provide good guidance with so little context. Can you please **[edit]** your post to be more *specific* about what you are trying to achieve, including a more detailed scenario?

Comment: Just fyip .. `(String) sfBorr.get('SSN__pc');` will actually not throw an exception but still return `null`, assuming `sfBorr` is a `Map`.

Comment: What more would you like to know? I basically want to have a method that puts the cast in a try catch and return nulls so i can use this method for all my fields, instead of having to write the code out for every field

Comment: @JayantDas sfBorr is an sObject

Comment: @BenArnao I made an assumption that it's a Map, but still, my comments above holds good. Even if its a `SObject`, and as long as the field exists on the `SObject`, if the value doesn't return anything, the casting here won't throw an exception.

Comment: @JayantDas Hmmm i see. Is there away to deal when that field doesn't exist?

Comment: You will end up getting a `SObjectException`, if the field doesn't exist. While I am not sure about your use case but you will always be aware of a field that you need to retrieve from a `SObject`, so its very unlikely you will end up getting that exception.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is a solution.

we have [getPopulatedFieldsAsMap](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_getPopulatedFieldsAsMap) method in Sobject

> getPopulatedFieldsAsMap Returns a map of populated field names and
>   their corresponding values. The map contains only the fields that have
>   been populated in memory for the SObject instance.

You can use it to your advantage.

```
(String) sfBorr.getPopulatedFieldsAsMap().get('SSN__pc');
```

This won't give you Invalid Field Exception. Happy Days

Comment: What are you trying to do? 

I tried `String id = (String) new Account().getPopulatedFieldsAsMap().get('Issd');
` it works